# Generate angular service based on graphql schema

Tags: angular, neo4j, graphql, code-generation, apollo

I have used AWS Appsync and I have been able to get auto-generated code for angular (an angular service was created for me with CRUD queries generated plus typescript types) based on a graphql schema file.

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/api#angular

I have also found [here](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-apollo-angular) (thanks @Daniel Rearden) how you can generate angular services from existing graphql queries. This is nice but it is really the next part that is time consuming, writing graphql queries everytime you change you schema. As AWS has managed to do, it is possible to generate crud queries based on the schema. Sure they will generally return all fields and require all fields as input parameter but that is fine.

My question is: is there some tool available to generate angular services with crud graphql queries and typescript types like the one AWS uses? Has anybody used this outside of AWS Appsync?

Example on how it works with AWS Appsync:

based on a schema like this:

```
type Todo @model { id: ID! name: String! description: String }
```

It will generate an angular service like this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import API, { graphqlOperation } from "@aws-amplify/api";
import { GraphQLResult } from "@aws-amplify/api/lib/types";
import * as Observable from "zen-observable";

export type CreateTodoInput = {
  id?: string | null;
  name: string;
  description?: string | null;
};

export type UpdateTodoInput = {
  id: string;
  name?: string | null;
  description?: string | null;
};

export type DeleteTodoInput = {
  id?: string | null;
};

export type ModelTodoFilterInput = {
  id?: ModelIDFilterInput | null;
  name?: ModelStringFilterInput | null;
  description?: ModelStringFilterInput | null;
  and?: Array<ModelTodoFilterInput | null> | null;
  or?: Array<ModelTodoFilterInput | null> | null;
  not?: ModelTodoFilterInput | null;
};

export type ModelIDFilterInput = {
  ne?: string | null;
  eq?: string | null;
  le?: string | null;
  lt?: string | null;
  ge?: string | null;
  gt?: string | null;
  contains?: string | null;
  notContains?: string | null;
  between?: Array<string | null> | null;
  beginsWith?: string | null;
};

export type ModelStringFilterInput = {
  ne?: string | null;
  eq?: string | null;
  le?: string | null;
  lt?: string | null;
  ge?: string | null;
  gt?: string | null;
  contains?: string | null;
  notContains?: string | null;
  between?: Array<string | null> | null;
  beginsWith?: string | null;
};

export type CreateTodoMutation = {
  __typename: "Todo";
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string | null;
};

export type UpdateTodoMutation = {
  __typename: "Todo";
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string | null;
};

export type DeleteTodoMutation = {
  __typename: "Todo";
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string | null;
};

export type GetTodoQuery = {
  __typename: "Todo";
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string | null;
};

export type ListTodosQuery = {
  __typename: "ModelTodoConnection";
  items: Array<{
    __typename: "Todo";
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string | null;
  } | null> | null;
  nextToken: string | null;
};

export type OnCreateTodoSubscription = {
  __typename: "Todo";
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string | null;
};

export type OnUpdateTodoSubscription = {
  __typename: "Todo";
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string | null;
};

export type OnDeleteTodoSubscription = {
  __typename: "Todo";
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string | null;
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class APIService {
  async CreateTodo(input: CreateTodoInput): Promise<CreateTodoMutation> {
    const statement = `mutation CreateTodo($input: CreateTodoInput!) {
        createTodo(input: $input) {
          __typename
          id
          name
          description
        }
      }`;
    const gqlAPIServiceArguments: any = {
      input
    };
    const response = (await API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(statement, gqlAPIServiceArguments)
    )) as any;
    return <CreateTodoMutation>response.data.createTodo;
  }
  async UpdateTodo(input: UpdateTodoInput): Promise<UpdateTodoMutation> {
    const statement = `mutation UpdateTodo($input: UpdateTodoInput!) {
        updateTodo(input: $input) {
          __typename
          id
          name
          description
        }
      }`;
    const gqlAPIServiceArguments: any = {
      input
    };
    const response = (await API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(statement, gqlAPIServiceArguments)
    )) as any;
    return <UpdateTodoMutation>response.data.updateTodo;
  }
  async DeleteTodo(input: DeleteTodoInput): Promise<DeleteTodoMutation> {
    const statement = `mutation DeleteTodo($input: DeleteTodoInput!) {
        deleteTodo(input: $input) {
          __typename
          id
          name
          description
        }
      }`;
    const gqlAPIServiceArguments: any = {
      input
    };
    const response = (await API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(statement, gqlAPIServiceArguments)
    )) as any;
    return <DeleteTodoMutation>response.data.deleteTodo;
  }
  async GetTodo(id: string): Promise<GetTodoQuery> {
    const statement = `query GetTodo($id: ID!) {
        getTodo(id: $id) {
          __typename
          id
          name
          description
        }
      }`;
    const gqlAPIServiceArguments: any = {
      id
    };
    const response = (await API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(statement, gqlAPIServiceArguments)
    )) as any;
    return <GetTodoQuery>response.data.getTodo;
  }
  async ListTodos(
    filter?: ModelTodoFilterInput,
    limit?: number,
    nextToken?: string
  ): Promise<ListTodosQuery> {
    const statement = `query ListTodos($filter: ModelTodoFilterInput, $limit: Int, $nextToken: String) {
        listTodos(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
          __typename
          items {
            __typename
            id
            name
            description
          }
          nextToken
        }
      }`;
    const gqlAPIServiceArguments: any = {};
    if (filter) {
      gqlAPIServiceArguments.filter = filter;
    }
    if (limit) {
      gqlAPIServiceArguments.limit = limit;
    }
    if (nextToken) {
      gqlAPIServiceArguments.nextToken = nextToken;
    }
    const response = (await API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(statement, gqlAPIServiceArguments)
    )) as any;
    return <ListTodosQuery>response.data.listTodos;
  }
  OnCreateTodoListener: Observable<OnCreateTodoSubscription> = API.graphql(
    graphqlOperation(
      `subscription OnCreateTodo {
        onCreateTodo {
          __typename
          id
          name
          description
        }
      }`
    )
  ) as Observable<OnCreateTodoSubscription>;

  OnUpdateTodoListener: Observable<OnUpdateTodoSubscription> = API.graphql(
    graphqlOperation(
      `subscription OnUpdateTodo {
        onUpdateTodo {
          __typename
          id
          name
          description
        }
      }`
    )
  ) as Observable<OnUpdateTodoSubscription>;

  OnDeleteTodoListener: Observable<OnDeleteTodoSubscription> = API.graphql(
    graphqlOperation(
      `subscription OnDeleteTodo {
        onDeleteTodo {
          __typename
          id
          name
          description
        }
      }`
    )
  ) as Observable<OnDeleteTodoSubscription>;
}
```

I am using [neo4j, apollo and angular with the grandstack starter](https://grandstack.io/).

I have seen ways to write your own templates to generate these types of code [here](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator). My hope is that somebody has created one of these templates for angular, similar to the one AWS has.

Comment: `graphql-code-generator` is not specific to any framework -- you can use it to create types for Angular based on your schema and any queries you're using. In fact, they have a plugin that will [generate your services for you](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-apollo-angular).

Comment: That is nice! The problem here is that it requires graphql queries in order to generate a service. I am interested in finding something that can take my schema.graphql file and generate an angular service WITH graphql queries (CRUD) generated for me like AWS does